# Is there a Reaction force acting upwards on a child standing uniformly on a plank when taking moments?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram

In the following diagram the child with a mass of 60kg at point c will show a weight force downwards of 60N but why does it not show an upward reaction force.
[original given diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhrXk.png)

I also tried solving and showing the forces upwards and downwards but it seems there is no force acting upwards at C like I have drawn [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cYt3.png)

Comment: No forces are shown on the first diagram.

Comment: The first diagram is the diagram in the question and the second diagram is the forces drawn for working out

Comment: You need to balance the torques on the board.

Comment: The reaction force acting upwards is applied on the person, not the board. So it shouldn't appear on the FBD for the board.